# How do I shrinkwrap an object to a curved surface cleanly and efficiently?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, vertices

I have a sphere and two eyes. I want to shrinkwrap the eyes onto the sphere's surface cleanly.

[image: sphere and two eyes]

The only way I know how to shrinkwrap ANYTHING is via the Shrinkwrap modifier, which crumples up the eyes when I try to stick them to the sphere, no matter how much I mess around with the settings.

[image: undesired result]

What is the correct way of doing this, while staying efficient on the vertex count? I don't want to end up subdividing the objects too much for such simple geometry.

.blend file: [image]

Comment: could you upload the blendfile?

Comment: Try to change the mode to project and enable negative and positive direction

Comment: @Denis This is what I get: http://i.imgur.com/Ful8ewm.png

Comment: @gladys I added it now.

Comment: @ROBOTunderscore you need to position the eye pieces closer and perpendicular to the surface for projection to work right.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to put Shrinkwrap modifier on the top of the modifiers stack.
Then in Shrinkwrap modifier change Mode to **Project** and in Direction enable **Positive**.
Then align the eye mesh tangentially to the surface of the sphere.

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is the desired result. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 3):

First I apllied the rotation and scale on the eye object. Then I moved the solidify modifier to the bottom. So the shrinkwrap modifier is in the middle. I changed the mode to project and the Axis to Y (in the shrinkwrap modifier)

[blendfile](http://[%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=441%22%20/%3E](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/441/))

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just need to make the eyes tangent to the sphere now.