# Shrinkwrap mesh onto another mesh

Tags: modeling

To model a costume inspired by the jacket bellow, I need to add the braide to it. I've tried doing so using the Shrinkwrap modifier (using the nearest surface point mode) but I have 3 issues:
1 - the braid has thickness, the Shrinkwrap modifier flattens the mesh. I thought of using a flat version of the braid then adding a solidify modifier but this would not be accurate, part of the braid goes on top  another part of the braid (like shoe laces) 
2 - I have distortions. I tried adding a subdivision surface modifier which helps a bit but not entirely. 
3 - the left part of the braid (the loop) shouldn't be on the jacket but rather over the edge of it, sort of "floating in the air".

[image]

Thanks for your help.

[image: Shrinkwrap]

Comment: for the flat aspect, the shrinkwrap can rely on a vertex group. You can weight paint the group to influence the shrinkwrap effect.

Comment: You should take a look at this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58181/need-help-with-deforming-a-mesh-over-another-mesh/58204#58204

Comment: don't use the shrinkwrap modifier directly (as it will flatten the embroidery) use a lattice to deform the object (or curve) and have the lattice use the shrinkrwrap modifier. See this links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44758/emboss-text-onto-curved-surface/44820#44820 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48823/deform-object-after-another-object/48841#48841

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing as cegaton...you could also use a mesh deform if you wanted but the lattice would be faster and easier to set up.

Answer (score 4):

The next version of Blender, version 2.78, currently available here https://builder.blender.org/download/ will contain major improvements to the Grease Pencil. With these, you could get a really fast starting point for your example. The new release allows you to define specific brushes for GP, and also to smooth the stroke, which is what I'm using in this example.

First, enable the options like this (note that this is only available in the release stated earlier) and draw the curve onto the mesh directly by holding down the <kbd>D</kbd> key and click-dragging:

[image: enable and draw]

The smoothing option will, as soon as you let go of the mouse, smooth out the stroke, cleaning it up and making it usable for the next step.

Then, convert the pencil drawing to a curve:

[image: convert pencil]

Finally, add some bevelling, subdivide the mesh, and set the smoothing option:

[image: final steps]